# Laravel DI - Can't solve Construct() must implement interface problem

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to do dependency injection.

But when i call my BananaService i get error:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to BananaService::\__construct() must be an instance of BananaFactory, instance of BananaModelFactory given.
```

which sounds quite logical, but it seemed to me that it should just return a BananaModelFactory class when it sees an BananaFactoryInterface, and not an error.

I have this BananaService:

```
class BananaService
{
    public function __construct(BananaFactory $factory) {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }
}
```

My BananaFactoryInterface:

```
interface BananaFactory
{
    public function make(array $attributes = []): BananaEntity;
}
```

And BananaModelFactory:

```
class BananaModelFactory
{
    public function make(): BananaEntity
    {
        return new Banana($attributes);
    }
}
```

I also added the following code to the AppServiceProvider:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(BananaFactory::class, BananaModelFactory::class);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to do an implementation in my BananaModelFactory.

`class BananaModelFactory implements BananaFactory {}`  instead of `class BananaModelFactory {}`.

I also found an excellent [github gist](https://gist.github.com/davejamesmiller/bd857d9b0ac895df7604dd2e63b23afe#binding-interfaces-to-implementations) in which it is written in detail about binding interfaces to implementation.